# meson 0.56.1 is failing to set correct host machine?

Tags: host, 32-bit, meson-build

I'm trying to build 32-bit mesa libraries from source, using the Debian mesa 20.3.5-1 source package. I've installed meson 0.56.1 from Debian's buster-backports because mesa 20.3.5 requires a newer meson than buster's native 0.49.2.

I do understand that I must specify a `--cross-file` to build 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system. This is the content of that file:

```
[host_machine]
system = 'linux'
cpu_family = 'x86'
cpu = 'i386'
endian = 'little'

[properties]
c_args = ['-m32']
cpp_args = ['-m32']

[binaries]
c = 'gcc'
cpp = 'g++'
ar = 'ar'
strip = 'strip'
pkgconfig = 'pkg-config'
windres = 'windres'
```

I'm specifying `[host_machine]` because I'm building (`build_machine`) on x86_64 but need to link the resulting libraries (`host_machine`) with existing 32-bit binaries.

I deleted and recreated a new empty `build` directory.

I invoke `meson` with a command line such as:

```
meson --cross-file i386.cross [... mesa-specific options ...] build .
```

Partial output:

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.56.1
Source dir: /tmp/mesa-20.3.5
Build dir: /tmp/mesa-20.3.5/build
Build type: cross build
Program python found: YES (/usr/bin/python)
Project name: mesa
Project version: 20.3.5
C compiler for the host machine: gcc (gcc 8.3.0 "gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0")
C linker for the host machine: gcc ld.bfd 2.31.1
C++ compiler for the host machine: g++ (gcc 8.3.0 "g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: g++ ld.bfd 2.31.1
C compiler for the build machine: cc (gcc 8.3.0 "cc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0")
C linker for the build machine: cc ld.bfd 2.31.1
C++ compiler for the build machine: c++ (gcc 8.3.0 "c++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0")
C++ linker for the build machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.31.1
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Target machine cpu family: x86
Target machine cpu: i386
Program python3 found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
```

The "Host machine" is simply wrong. I need 32-bit libraries. How to insist?

Comment: Just to double check, the `target` machine is correct, you didn't happen to use the `[target_machine]` section of the cross file instead of the `[host_machine]` did you?

Comment: I used `cat` to display the `--cross-file` as posted above.

Comment: Hey, did you fix the issue? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No, sorry. I gave up on 32-bit builds on buster.